# How to handle excel software using python?

Tags: excel, python-3.x, vba

I want to handle Open,creat new file, Saveas, delete etc using python

Answer (score 0):

Use pyexcel to handle the file.
You don't handle the software (excel.exe) therefore you handle the files such as .csv or .xlsx.

```
$ pip install pyexcel
```

Here the documentation:
[Read the docs pyexce](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pyexcel/latest/pyexcel.pdf)

Sample:

```
>>> import pyexcel
>>> reader = pyexcel.Reader("example.csv""")
>>> print reader[1][1]
5
```

Answer (score 0):

Openpyxl is a great module that I have been using to work with Excel files ([docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html)):

```
pip3 install openpyxl
```

creating and saving a Workbook:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook    
wb = Workbook()
wb.save('balances.xlsx')
```

Selecting a specific worksheet:

```
worksheet = wb["Sheet1"]
```

Reading and writing data from worksheet:

```
c = ws['A4']
ws['A4'] = 4
```

or:

```
d = ws.cell(row=4, column=2)
```